# Why can't I predict for new observations in my linear model in R

Tags: r

Please read this before insisting it's already been answered. I've reviewed similar questions to no avail. I have the very simple goal of building a simple linear model and predicting new values. Here's my code:

```
a <- c(9024492, 8379054, 8962608, 9095940, 8468694, 9215560, 9082280)

b <- c(3747494, 3258151, 3795750, 2976020, 3185280, 3955260, 3837480)

model_data <- data.frame(A = a, B = b)

model <- lm(formula = A ~ B, data = model_data)

new_points <- c(3500000, 3600000, 3700000)
new_points <- data.frame(B = new_points)

predict(model, new_data = new_points)
```

And here is the unexpected output:

```
> predict(model, new_data = new_points)
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7 
8988178 8760036 9010676 8628501 8726062 9085043 9030131
```

Comment: Ah... but wait, why didn't I get an unused argument error?

Comment: Because `predict` takes a `...` argument. Only functions without `...` can know for sure whether your argument is used or not and give an unused argument error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the right variable, i.e. `newdata` instead of `new_data`:

```
> predict(model, newdata = new_points)
      1       2       3 
8872791 8919413 8966035
```

See `?predict.lm` for more.